# Use Promises simply to control execution order

Tags: angularjs, asynchronous, promise

I'm wondering if this is possible, but I have a series of functions where promises would be a perfect solution for ordering and whatnot, however these functions do not depend on the data from previous promises. I would like to use promises to control execution order but I still need the functions to have access to the scope closure.

Here is some context as to why. On the client I have some object. Various actions cause the client to save/update this object. We recently had a race condition where two actions were done so close together the server actually corrupted the object in the database. I thought it would work well to use a promise chain so update requests will wait until there are no other pending update requests. The update information I need to send to the server obviously exists in the scope so I need to be able to access that when pendingRequestPromise resolves.

I essentially have something that looks like this:

```
scope.$on("UPDATE", function(event, callback){
    $http.post("update", scope.myObj).success(function(updateInfo){
        callback(updateInfo);
    });
};
```

If the user does the right actions fast enough, I send 2 objects to the server which caused some problems last week.

Comment: Can you show your current solution in your question (the one that results in the race condition)?

Comment: I updated the question, does it make sense what is happening and what I am trying to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest using the $q service somewhat like this:

```
//disable all stuff you want to user not to click with ng-disable
$scope.pageLoading=true;

var update1Promise = $http.post("update1", scope.myObj).success(function(updateInfo){
        callback(updateInfo);
    }),
    update2Promise = $http.post("update2", scope.myObj).success(function(updateInfo){
        callback(updateInfo);
    }),
    update3Promise = $http.post("update3", scope.myObj).success(function(updateInfo){
        callback(updateInfo);
    });

$q.all([update1Promise,update2Promise,update3Promise])then(function() {
    $scope.pageLoading=false;
});
```

Comment: Yeah looks like that will work really well. I had some confusion about how promises work but this sorted it out. thanks!